# 4 bit mux input/outputs

Tags: multiplexer

If i have a 4 input mux with the output being in the form of

S1 AND NOT(s0)

MY truth table therefore looks like the following (remember NOT(S0)).

```
S1   S0   X
0    0    0A
0    1    0B
1    0    1C
1    1    0D
```

Does that mean that the inputs have to be A=0 B =0 C=1 and D=0 in order for the output to be the above boolean equation?

Comment: DV because the question as written is excessively narrow, and doesn't clearly state that the motivation is to use a mux to implement an arbitrary logic function.

Comment: Would be glad to remove (and upvote) if the question is reworded to require more than just a yes/no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's how you would implement the logic function with a multiplexer.